# How to access User-Provided environment variables in cloud foundry?

Tags: deployment, environment-variables, cloud, cloud-foundry, microservices

I'm aware of setting environment variables in `manifest.yml` by doing following

```
--- 
- applications:
  - name:
    .
    .
    env:
      MY_ENV_VAR: 'my-var-value'
```

How do I access `MY_ENV_VAR` in my program (python for example) ?

Additionally, I only want to access this variable in cloud foundry environment. While doing local development, I would like to use some hard-coded value, how do I separate these two scenarios (python example again) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snippet in Python:

```py
import os

if os.getenv('VCAP_APPLICATION'):
  # cf environment
  my_env_var = os.getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')
else:
  # local
  my_env_var = some_default_value
```